# Counting numbers in a file, in C

Tags: c, file, int

I'm trying to count the number of numbers in a text file. I have the following code:

```
FILE *f1;
char pathname[4096];
snprintf(pathname, 4095, "%s%d%s\n", "Key_", 2, ".txt");

if( ( f1 = fopen(pathname, "w+") ) == NULL )
    perror("fopen");

for(int i = 0; i<20; ++i)
    fprintf(f1, "%d\n", i+1);

int sum = 0;
int num;
while( fscanf(f1, "%d", &num) != EOF )
    ++sum;

printf("number of numbers: %d\n", sum);
```

This code says the number of numbers in the file is zero. However, if I fclose the file stream and refopen it, the sum will be 20 as expected. Any idea as to why this happens?
Thanks

Comment: or close it and reopen in read mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file pointer at which reads occur is shared with writes. Since `w+` creates a new file or truncates an existing file, in the beginning the file is empty. As you write to the file the file pointer is moved forward and always points to the end of file. Now, when you read at that position, you will hit EOF right away.

After writing, but before reading, seek to the beginning with `fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `fseek` to reset the current position in the file before you read from the beginning again: `fseek(f1, 0, SEEK_SET);`